# Use WORKSPACE drive in Jenkins Scripted Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

This seems to be straight forward requirement where I need to extract drive for Jenkins so I can build remaining path. 
In JenkinsFile.xml, I have following

```
def drive = "${WORKSPACE}".substring(0, 1) // This saves drive as "C" as expected
echo "set MYVAR=${drive}" // this gets replaced and prints set MYVAR =C
withEnv([ ' MYVAR =${drive}']) { // However, this does expands to MYVAR =C as expected
        bat ' set MYVAR =${drive}' // This gets execute as set MYVAR =${drive}
        // Expected is set MYVAR =C
    }
```

I also tried

```
withEnv([ ' MYVAR ="${drive}"']) { // However, this does expands to MYVAR =C as expected
withEnv([ ' MYVAR ="drive"']) { // However, this does expands to MYVAR =C as expected
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Fix was to update script:

```
withEnv([ ' MYVAR =' + drive]) {
        bat ' set MYVAR =' +drive 
    }
```

Comment: you should use `"` ,rather than `'`. More detail https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#string-interpolation